# How to pickup old session handling from Drupal after using SimpleSAMLphp?

Tags: php, session, drupal-7, shibboleth, simplesamlphp

Code example:

```
<?php

require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/simplesaml/lib/_autoload.php');
session_write_close();
session_set_save_handler(new SessionHandler(), true);
$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();

$samlSession = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$samlSession->cleanup();


$_SESSION['saml'] = $attributes; // <-- this does not work, since altering $_SESSION at this point is useless. reading out $_SESSION on a another page does not have anything saved after calling the SimpleSAMLphp functions
```

---

We are using SimpleSAMLphp on our website as SP to use with a Shibboleth IDP. The server cant run the apache modules or memcache so we need to use PHP sessions. On the [simplesamlphp documentation](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp#section_6) it says:

> If we are using PHP sessions in SimpleSAMLphp and in the application
> we are protecting, SimpleSAMLphp will close any existing session when
> invoked for the first time, and its own session will prevail
> afterwards. If you want to restore your own session after calling
> SimpleSAMLphp, you can do so by cleaning up the session like this:

```
$session = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$session->cleanup();
```

> If you don't cleanup SimpleSAMLphp's session and try to use $_SESSION
> afterwards, you won't be using your own session and all your data is
> likely to get lost or inaccessible.

The problem is, that is exactly the issue we are facing. Whatever I write into `$_SESSION` after loading the SSP files is lost at the new page request.

Now, we are using Drupal 7. I dont know how to implement the documentation code in a Drupal environment:

```
// use custom save handler
session_set_save_handler($handler); // what is this? what is $handler?
session_start();

// close session and restore default handler
session_write_close();
session_set_save_handler(new SessionHandler(), true);

// use SimpleSAML\Session
$session = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$session->cleanup();
session_write_close();

// back to custom save handler
session_set_save_handler($handler); // how do i get the Drupal handler?
session_start();
```

So how do I implement the session swapping in a Drupal 7 environment? Or generally, how do I get a session handler/ reference?

Drupal itself does this at [some point](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21session.inc/7.x) in `session.inc`:

```
session_set_save_handler('_drupal_session_open', '_drupal_session_close', '_drupal_session_read', '_drupal_session_write', '_drupal_session_destroy', '_drupal_session_garbage_collection');
```

But calling any Drupal session function didnt work, `$_SESSION` was always unwritable (or rather didnt actually save) after using SimpleSAMLphp.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

If you are not using SimpleSAMLphp's stand-alone web UI, this might work:

```
require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/simplesaml/lib/_autoload.php');

$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();

$samlSession = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$samlSession->cleanup();
    
$_SESSION['saml'] = $attributes;
```

It should keep your original session handler (which would also be used by SSP), then reload the old session ID by restoring previous session id and name.

---

Original answer:

Looking at the SimpleSAMLphp [session handler's code](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/fb00c067ece6ec6893e79810fd99a9126e76d639/lib/SimpleSAML/SessionHandlerPHP.php#L110) it should already recover the previous session - If there are any active in the moment of invoking SimpleSAMLphp.

I would say that what happens here is that you manually closed the session by using `session_write_close();` before SimpleSAMLPhp started theirs, so when you closed SimpleSAMLphp's session, the previous one could not be restored.

I would try to do as follows (I assumed it is the code you are using):

```
// If I recall well, Drupal already starts session for you, 
// but if it's not the case in your configuration, go ahead and uncomment following lines
// session_set_save_handler($handler);
// session_start();

// use SimpleSAML\Session
$session = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$session->cleanup();

// Just resume your $_SESSION use
$_SESSION['myAttribute'] = 'myValue';
```

Comment: ssp does the closing in their tutorial though. if i am correct, this function just writes the variables into the session file on the server.

Comment: You are right, then my question is: are you using the SimpleSAMLphp's stand-alone web UI? Otherwise the doc states that this might not be a problem. `session_write_close();` writes variables into the session storage and ends the session -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Edited my answer if the answer to my question is no.